# calling presentModalViewController within UIView class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

my class is UIView, I cant change it to UIViewController because its being called by loadNibNamed within another class.

I know that presentModalViewController sends message to UIViewController, so how i can work on this issue within my UIView class?

This causes crash which is normal:

```
[self presentModalViewController ....
```

Tried this but the called view dosent get pulled:

```
.h
@class Setting;
@interface SettingProfile : UIView ...
Setting *setting;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Setting *setting;

.m
@synthesize setting;
...
[setting presentModalViewController ....
```

i tried  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490536/presentmodalviewcontroller-from-uiview)  but it wasn't much help.

Comment: What is `Setting` a subclass of?

Comment: Looks like it is a UIView subclass ...

Comment: Setting is UIViewController, where i am calling SettingProfile by loadNibNamed

Answer (score 2):

You can't use presentModalViewController on a UIView, this just isn't going to work. You have a couple of options:

- Refactor so your Setting stuff is in a UIViewController subclass.
- Add your Setting UIView subclass as a subview of your current view controller view. Animate the view so that it pops up like the presentModal animation.

Seems like you aren't keen on the first option, so to do the second you will need to:

- Set the frame on your Setting UIView to be offscreen (off the bottom).
- [Start](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations%3acontext%3a) an animation block.
- Add the Setting view as a subview of your main view controller view.
- Set the frame to be on screen (so the animation block will move the view from below the bottom screen edge up onto the screen).
- [Commit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/commitAnimations) the animation block.

Comment: Many thanks RedBlue,, the 2nd option sounds the best solution, i will give it a try n let u know. thx again for your prompt help.

Comment: @Artist_inMood No problem. Good luck with it.